# How best to modify sql queries with table prefix

Tags: php, mysql, prefix

I'm creating a new CMS which features an installer.

I'm allowing table names to prefixed with a custom string.

What is the recommended method of modyfying the sql with the prefixed table names?

Will I have to add the DB_PREFIX in to every query or is there any way it can be done afterwards in my database class by modyfing the sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to write all your SQL queries with tables enclosed with braces and use function which replaces these braces with wanted database prefix.

Instead of writing standard SQL query, embrace table names with e.g. curly braces like:

```
//SQL query in your code
$query=prefixQuery("SELECT name FROM {customers} WHERE id=$id");
```

and define simple function that will replace left { with prefix, and remove right }:

```
define(DB_PREFIX,'myprefix_');

function prefixQuery($query)
{
   return str_replace('}','',str_replace('{',DB_PREFIX,$query));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prefix to every query, yes.

You can also parse every query with the function str_replace like this :

```
str_replace('mytable', 'prefix_mytable', $Query);
```

I will go for option number 1, less load.

HINT: If you create a new CMS, provide a DB class and add automatically the prefix.

Comment: Thats a great idea but the table names could be unkown.

I guess I could: 
1. get a list of tables from the database
2. remove the prefix from the names
3. store the table names without the prefix in a $from array
4. store the table names with the prefix in a $to array
5. do a str replace with the from and to arrays on the sql

Is that the best way do you think?

Comment: Yes, you know the table name. When you run the query, let's say SELECT * FROM supertable, you know that the table name is supertable. So you just have to do `SELECT * FROM '.str_replace('supertable', 'prefix_supertable', $Table).' WHERE 1`

Comment: That's basically the same as DB_PREFIX . table_name though...

I tried what I wrote above but it breaks where the same strings used in table names are used in column names.